# Nuances of Hibernate Session

Tags: java, sql, database, spring, hibernate

My question is regarding hibernate- so say you have two objects that you are queuing up to save to your database. These are objects have exactly the same values for every field. My hibernate is configured to auto-flush after 50 queries so let's assume it will not flush these objects to the database immediately upon passage to the hibernate session. Will hibernate save each of these objects to the database as distinct entities (so it will save the duplicate records as 'distinct' records), or does it recognize that these objects have the exact same value and only save one instance of these mirrored objects to the database?

Comment: do they have an Id field and what are their values?

Comment: The id field is sequence generated and handled by hibernate. The field values are clobs and strings.

Comment: What are their values at save time?

Comment: I'm not getting multiple copies of the records at all, I'm only getting one if that. Somewhere along the way I'm losing records and I don't understand why. I've got log4j setup with it as well and it's producing outputs for every record that should also be saved into the db

Comment: please show us your code also show us your table structure

Comment: As long as you not answer i can not help.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you end up with one or two entities in the database depends on the implementation of equals() (and hashcode, respectively). If the objects will be considered equal you will end up with one entity, but if the are not you will end up with two.

You have to be extra careful when using autogenerated surrogate keys: Before saving the objects for the first time the keys have not been assigned. Therefore any equals() implementation cannot rely on key equality. You must ensure that you handle this special condition
.

Comment: Okay, so since I have no equals or hashcode implemented for those objects it's probably my supposition is correct- that hibernate is viewing the objects as a duplicate and thus only saving one copy into the db?

Comment: I don't think this is correct though, the default behavior would be to check if the objects are referencing the same object wouldn't it? this is not the case, these are distinct objects occupying distinct memory locations.

Comment: Yes, the default implementation of equals() is to return true if and only if they are identical (x=y). If you have created two instances of your entity you will end up with two entities (=rows) in the DB. However, if the objects are identical then adding them to the session twice will result in only one entity.

Comment: Are you sure you creating two instances? One reason you are loosing data could be that you are reusing and instance and just apply new values before adding it to the session.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is regarding hibernate- so say you have two objects that
>   you are queuing up to save to your database.

Let's rephrase - we have two entities that we want to persist in database.

> These are objects have exactly the same values for every field.

In Java there is an object identity implemented by `equals` (and `hashcode`). In database there is row identity - primary key which identifies unique row (which translates is unique instance). As we are mapping instance of our Entity to row in table, the way to differentiate between two instance of the same class(same entity) is to provide unique primary key to each instance. In JPA (Hibernate is implementation of JPA) you need to annotate field (attribute of Entity) with `@Id` annotation, such it can be uniquely identified.

Below class is Entity class with unique ID.

```
@Entity
public MyClass

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
```

You can either provide unique ID each time you persist or you can use auto-generation with `@GeneratedValue`. There are different generation strategies depending on underlying database.

Comment: Yes, all this I understand and have done this. They have an Id object field that is annotated with the JPA annotation. I'm letting hibernate handle the id creation, because it's being populated by a sequence database side. But I'm losing records, they cease to exist

Comment: Please provide more information how do you persist and how transaction is controlled. I just provided this information to indicate that Java identity does not matter for JPA, it has it's own identity understanding.

Comment: AOP spring transaction management, the method that saves the objects is annotated with @Transactional tag with an isolation level of serializable. I'm using Spring Data JPA so I'm not even managing when an object will persist, that functionality is abstracted away from me if my understanding is correct- I save the object with the JPA repository.

Comment: Please post you configuration and classes, it is hard to understand without them (at least for me :) )